# Escaping stripes from MySQL execute command

Tags: mysql, bash

This should be so simple, but I cannot get it to work.
I am automating a release procedure on our server using bash (sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

oldDatabase=${1:-}
newDatabase=${2:-}
dbPassword=${3:-}
dbuser=${4:-}

if [ ! -z $oldDatabase ] ; then


        mysql -u "$dbuser" "-p$dbPassword" -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $newDatabase"
        mysqldump -u "$dbuser" "-p$dbPassword" $oldDatabase | mysql -u "$dbuser" "-p$dbPassword" $newDatabase;
else
        echo "DB file: '$oldDatabase' not found/given!"
fi
```

This works great for database names like `test_something`, `blabla`, etc...

However, the current names of the database have a lot of stripes in it: `rel-3-3-0.dev`. I cannot get this to work, I keep getting a SQL error on the command. (ERROR 1064 in MySQL)

I guess the stripes in the query are not accepted by the command line MySQL variant, so I added backticks:

```
mysql -u "$dbuser" "-p$dbPassword" -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `$newDatabase`"
```

But this does not seem to work in either? (ERROR 1064 in MySQL)

---

Any way to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, it seems to work like this:

```
 mysql -u "$dbuser" "-p$dbPassword" -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`$newDatabase\`"
```